# Can ping from VPC 1 to router and VPC2, but can't ping from switch to VPC2 or router

Tags: switch, router, cisco-ios, ping, gns3

I have a simple, linear topology in GNS3 that goes like this.

VPC1 > Switch > Router > VPC2

I have the default static IP Routes on the router set to 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Ethernet0/1 and Ethernet1/0

I can ping from VPC1 to VPC2 without an issue. However, when I try to ping from the switch (Managed Cisco Switch) to PC2 I get a success rate of 0. I also can't ping the interface 1/0 of the router (which connects to VPC2).
But I can successfully ping, from the switch, both PC1 and Router interface 0/0 (the one connected to the switch)

The IP on the switch is configured to its VLAN1 interface, which is in UP status.

So my questions are:

1/  Why can't I ping "past" the Ethernet0/0 interface of the router from the switch?

2/ Why is the ping directly from VPC1 to VPC2 successful whereas the one from the switch isn't? It's a linear topology, so shouldn't it be taking the same path?

Here is the Switch configuration.

```
hostname CiscoSwitch
!
boot-start-market
boot-end-marker
!
!
logging discriminator EXCESS severity drops 6 msg-body drops EXCESSCOLL
logging buffered 50000
logging console discriminator EXCESS!
no aaa new-model
no ipv6 cef
ipv6 multicast rpf use-bgp
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
no ip domain-lookup
ip cef
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 duplex auto
!
 interface Ethernet0/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 duplex auto
interface Ethernet0/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 duplex auto
!
 interface Ethernet1/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 duplex auto
interface Ethernet1/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet2/0
 duplex auto
!
 interface Ethernet2/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet2/2
 duplex auto
interface Ethernet2/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet3/0
 duplex auto
!
 interface Ethernet3/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet3/2
 duplex auto
interface Ethernet3/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.168.1.253 255.255.0.0
 !
 ip default-gateway 172.168.0.254
 !
 no ip http server
 !
 !
 !
 !
 control-plane
 !
 !
 line con 0
  exec-timeout 0 15
  privilege level 15
  logging synchronous
 line aux 0
  exec-timeout 0 0
  privilege level 15
  logging synchronous
 line vty 0 4
  login
 !
 end
```

router configuration

```
hostname R3600
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$iP0R$xM8wSmb7p7JOMCFVddGXe1
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
clock timezone GMT -6
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description "Interfaz de Ethernet 0, conectada al Switch"
 ip address 172.168.0.254 255.255.0.0
 half-duplex
 ipv6 address 2001:CAFE:DEA:1::25/64
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 description "Interfaz de Ethernet 1, conectada al equipo 2"
 ip address 172.169.0.254 255.255.0.0
 half-duplex
 ipv6 address 2001:CAFE:DEA::25/64
 ipv6 address FE80::1 link-local
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
```

and vpc2

```
set pcname PC2
ip 172.169.0.252 172.169.0.254 16
ip 2001:cafe:dea::1/64
```

I am very new to this topic, so if there's some information I could provide, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not included your network device configurations, so we cannot answer your question. You can edit the question to include the configurations.

Comment: I have added the configs

Comment: First, never set your ethernet interface duplex to half because you can really mess up with a duplex mismatch. Always leave the speed and duplex set to auto.

Comment: That was a default configuration, I just changed it to auto though. But it doesn't seem to be related with the ability to ping VPC2

Comment: No, it is not related to that, but can cause problems. That should not be the default.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use public addresses that you don't own. For a private network, use only addresses from RFC 1918 (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16). The addresses you're using belong to AOL.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following commands:
 `show vlan id 1`, `show int vlan1`, `show mac address-table dynamic vlan 1`. What you have as a setup *should* work and there is no obvious reason why it doesn't. Maybe it's a problem with the emulation software (EVE/GNS)